# Manifest file doesn't conform to the schema. This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides:FocusedInboxTab'

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, ribbonx

I've built a Outlook add-in for new email. When I'm trying to make it available for inbox, its saying the error.

```
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="FocusedInboxTab">
        <Label resid="TabLabel" />
        <Icon>
          <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
          <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
          <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
        </Icon>
        <GroupBy>
          <bt:Properties>
            <bt:Property Name="System.MessageList.DateReceived" />
          </bt:Properties>
        </GroupBy>
        <TabSettings>
          <TabColor>#E6E6E6</TabColor>
          <HighContrastTabColor>#FFFFFF</HighContrastTabColor>
          <ShowOn>
            <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
              <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
              <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
            </Rule>
          </ShowOn>
          <HideOn>
            <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Compose" />
          </HideOn>
        </TabSettings>
      </ExtensionPoint>
```

I'm expecting to get my add-in when I tap on outlook inbox options.

Comment: Here is a link to Outlook Add-in manifest doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates a problem with your ribbon markup. You have skipped a possible and allowed child element of the `ExtensionPoint` element in your ribbon markup.

The following diagram shows the hierarchy of elements used to define add-in commands. Under the `ExtensionPoint` element you can place the `CustomTab/OfficeTab` or `OfficeMenu` according to the scheme:

[image: ribbon scheme for office add-ins]

See [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?tabs=xmlmanifest) for more information.